# How does Js.cast() perform its type checking?

Tags: gwt, gwt-jsinterop, gwt-elemental

I'm using GWT 2.9 with elemental2-1.0.0-RC1.

The following code throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime:

```java
DocumentRange documentRange = Js.cast(DomGlobal.document); // Fails
Range range = documentRange.createRange(); // Never reaches here
```

When I change to use an `Js.uncheckedCast()` instead, it succeeds:

```java
DocumentRange documentRange = Js.uncheckedCast(DomGlobal.document);
Range range = documentRange.createRange(); // Works
```

The documentation for `Js.uncheckedCast()` says:

> "You should always prefer regular casting over this (unless you know what you are doing!)."

I don't know why I'm having to use it, so I'm feeling nervous. Can someone explain how `Js.cast()` performs its type-checking and why I need to use an `Js.uncheckedCast()` in this instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Js.cast()` is a way to cheat a bit, and do something that the Java language will not permit, but might actually be legal. Ignoring "how it actually works", the idea is that you can now get past issues where Java would complain, even if it turns out to be legit.

An example could be where you take a `java.lang.Double` or `double` and want to treat it as a `JsNumber` so you can call toPrecision(2) on it. Since `java.lang.Double` is final, it isn't legal to cast to an unrelated type, but Java doesn't know that in GWT, Double is really just a js `Number`. So, instead you can perform the cast with `Js.cast()`. The compiler will insert a runtime type check in there, verifying at runtime that your number is in fact a JS Number instance.

Another example could be trying to extend some native type that elemental2 provides, either to implement a workaround for a missing feature, or to do something browser-specific. Your new class may not extend the existing class - from JS's perspective this is okay, you are just describing the API that you know will exist at runtime. As such, we need to avoid the Java language check of "does this cast even make sense?", and just tell the compiler to try it.

On the other hand, you can "lie" to the compiler with `Js.uncheckedCast()`. This is used in cases where you are even asking the runtime to skip the check, and just pretend that it will work. This can let you do weird things, like treating Strings as if they were arrays, or solve cross-frame problems. No runtime check will be emitted, so instead you might just get a TypeError if a method/property is missing, instead of a proper ClassCastException.

---

In elemental2-dom 1.0.0-RC1, there is a class called `DocumentRange`, but it doesnt really make any sense - it is declared as a class, which means it can be type checked in JS, but the browser spec says that it should be an "interface" (which in JS-land means that it just is a description of a type, rather than something you can typecheck). https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level2-DocumentRange-method-createRange

This bug is inherited from closure-compiler, which claims that this has a constructor: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/6a418aa/externs/browser/w3c_range.js#L241-L251

The fix is for closure-compiler to refer to this as an interface, and for a new release of elemental2 to be made so you can use this.

---

There are two workarounds you can make here. The first is to cheat with `Js.uncheckedCast(DomGlobal.document)` and say "yes, I know that the `Document` is not `instanceof DocumentRange`, but that's because there is no such class as `DocumentRange`, so just pretend it worked so I can call `createRange()` on it". This is what you are doing already - it hides the fact there is a bug, but at the end of the day it works.

The "correct" answer is to declare your own `DocumentRange`, and do a `Js.cast()` to that instead. This is still gross - you have to keep your new interface around until closure gets fixed, and then elemental2 gets released, and then you have to remember to clean it up.

In this case, I would suggest lying to GWT and using `Js.uncheckedCast()` - there is only a single method on here, and it is unlikely to change in a meaningful way.

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/pull/3602 to fix this.

Comment: Thanks Colin. Amazing answer.